# create a matrix with a matrix + vector (features + label)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How can I create a new matrix with features and label in Python? E.g. in scikit-learn: how can I "see" (print) a new table with features + label: [5. 2.5 1.5 0.2 0] where the last 0 is the label of this sample. Plus: I created training and test data sets - how I can "flag" the basic data with training or test set member? (I am new at Python)

```
feature matrix
    [[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
     [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
     [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
     [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]]

    label vector
    [0 1 0 2]

     how can I "put" together into one matrix?
    [[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 0]
     [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2 1]
     [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 0]
     [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 2]]
```

**code:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset = load_iris()

print ((iris_dataset['data']))
print ((iris_dataset['target']))

print("Type of data: {}".format(type(iris_dataset['data'])))
print("Type of target: {}".format(type(iris_dataset['target'])))


Type of data: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Type of target: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: are these lists or numpy arrays? Could you post a [mcve] , preferrably python code that can make these example inputs so we can copy-paste and run the code ourselves?

Comment: You can use `np.c_[iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target']]`. However, I'm not sure if that's really what you want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to easily concatenate arrays in this manner.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset = load_iris()

print(iris_dataset['data'].shape)
print(iris_dataset['target'].shape)

import numpy as np
result = np.hstack((iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'].reshape(-1, 1)))

print(result.shape)

#Output:
(150, 4)
(150,)
(150, 5)
```